# What is [review]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-wiki

What exactly is [review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review) supposed to mean? By looking at the 267 questions with this tag, I can't find much similarities besides having the word "review" in the text. I think it should either be provided with a tag wiki that'd make its intent clear or possibly burninated.

Comment: @rene: you misunderstand, I meant the questions didn't have much in common among themselves. They were mostly normal questions, not ones you'd close. But this tag related to different things in them. Right now, this tag is completely unclear.

Comment: @rene: the problem here is not really the questions, but the tag... the questions are a separate issue

Comment: We disagree on that I am afraid. A useless tag is more often than not on bad questions. If you don't want to get the tag cleaned-up you shoud make that clear in your post. Just ask for a proper wiki-tag in that case.

Comment: @rene: so question deletion is necessary for tag removal?

Comment: No, if you ask us to look at a tag we should take every action that is needed to raise the quality which include editing, closing, voting, deleting, retagging and update the tag wiki. And I tried to convey the idea that a near useless tag is often used on questions that need one of more ealier mentioned actions

Comment: @rene: all right, thank you, I think I understand what you're saying... sorry, I'm not very experienced with how things are handled on Meta ><

Comment: So the questions with this tag should be ... reviewed?

Answer (score 4):

I've cleaned up the tag a little.

All [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone), [itunesconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itunesconnect), [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) and [app-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-store) questions which had [review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review) and where about the app approval process were retagged to [appstore-approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appstore-approval).
The remaining questions in those tags are basically about linking, reminding and showing the app review page in the app for the user. Those seem like recommendation requests, because a specific link must be used. I haven't yet acted on it.

All [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) questions ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review+facebook)) seem to be about a similar store approval process. Should we create a new tag for that?

Most [gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gerrit) and [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) questions were retagged to [code-review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-review).

The remaining questions (currently [174](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review+-itunesconnect+-ios+-iphone+-app-store+-apple+-git+-gerrit) out of [206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review)) are likely implementing some kind of review system. It seems unnecessary to convey this information in a tag as those are wildly different technologies and nobody can be an expert in those. Burnination seems in order.

Comment: Please go to http://stackoverflow.com/review/close, filter by `appstore-approval review` and use your votes.